# Are there any cases when an abstraction should inherit ISerializable?

Tags: .net, abstraction, serialization

There is a @Mark Seemann's [cite](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3726#issuecomment-163535556) from a conversation which states that an abstraction must never implement `IDisposable`:

> I like how @nblumhardt [put it almost six years ago](http://cca.codeplex.com/discussions/82987):
>
> > an interface [...] generally shouldn't be disposable. There's no way for the one defining an interface to foresee all possible implementations of it - you can always come up with a disposable implementation of practically any interface.

Is this applicable for the `ISerializable` interface as well (meaning that an *abstraction* must never implement it)?

Comment: You would implement `ISerializable` when you want the abstraction to have a custom serialization implementation, if I understand your question correctly.  Inheriting from `ISerializable` compels the implementer to create an implementation, so you would inherit from it when you want to *require* it.

Comment: In the discussions I mentioned the point was that it's not possible to _foresee_ if _all the implementers_ will need `IDisposable` which is the reason _not to make_ the abstraction as `IDisposable`. It moves this decision 'down' to the concrete implementers. You're right that inheriting `ISerializable` compels the implementer, but how do I know if all the future implementations will need to be serializable?

Comment: You have to decide for yourself if that's the right thing to do.  The `IDisposable` example only really applies to those things that dispose **unmanaged** resources, so if you don't have to do that, you don't need to force people to implement `IDisposable`, unless you want to co-opt it for closing database connections, closing HTML tags (yes, it's been abused to do that), and such things.

Comment: You would have to come up with a good use case to extend ISerializable from your interface.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of one.

Comment: @Jon Raynor, if I understand you correctly, your point is that an abstraction should not be `ISerializable`. I tend to agree with that, but would like to check if somebody could share an example where it _might_ be necessary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey good comment, but database connections are unmanaged resources. I personally feel the using block is more useful than simply for disposing resources. We don't have anything else like it in C#, so IDisposable is a valid way to guarantee a bit of code run on exit of the block.

Comment: @FrankHileman: There's plenty of documentation about how `IDisposable` works if anyone is willing to look.  While I'm not in pedantic mode right now, the term "managed" is generally used to refer to the garbage-collective nature of the .NET framework, and yes, `IDisposable` is sometimes used for other things besides that.

Answer (score 1):

"An abstraction" and "an interface" are not the same thing. Classes, structures, methods, and other things are all abstractions. The discussion you quote is specifically about interfaces.

Interfaces in .net are like mixins without any implementation (a poor man's mixin). They specify what the class or structure must ultimately implement. For that reason, you should minimize the number of members in the interface, so that is more easily implemented. This means you should also minimize inheritance in interface design.

An interface inheriting from ISerializable means that all interface implementations must implement ISerializable. If the methods using your interface require ISerializable, in addition to other things, of course it makes sense to inherit from it. But this particular interface is rarely used.